# What is an efficient way to read data from an image with an arbitrary number of pixel components? (Python, PIL)

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, pixel, anaconda

I am working on a project in Python that requires me to be able to get pixel values across an entire image, in order to weigh their similarity (it is an image segmentation project). I am using the PIL Image module (and every other package in Anaconda).

Much of our algorithim is fairly developed, though I am returning to this because as of right now it can only handle grayscale images. This is done currently as so:

```
self.dataImage = Image.open(self.file, mode = 'r')
self.data = self.dataImage.getdata()
```

I later inspect it with

```
print("data: {}".format(list(data.GetImageData())))
```

This returns a sequence of integers corresponding to the intensity of each pixel of the image. I wanted to make a simple modification to allow if to accept RGB images also, by making each item in the sequence an array instead of a single integer, so it would be able to support images with any arbitrary number of pixel components (such as 3, for RGB).

Is there a simple way to do this through the PIL Image module? I looked through the documentation and here on StackOverflow, and this is the best I could find:

```
self.allPixels = self.dataImage.load()
    self.data = []
    for i in range(self.width):
        for j in range(self.height):
            currentPixel = self.allPixels[i,j]
            self.data.append(currentPixel)

print("data: {}".format(data.GetImageData()))
```

This is supposed to return the data in the form of (255,255,255) (for example) for each pixel. What should the output of it be when looking at a grayscale image? Because the output of the first method I described, and the second, are comepletely different.

The first (using getData()) gives

```
data: [0, 0, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 5, 1, 0, 0, 5, 6, 6, 2, 0, 0, 2, 7, 8 ....
```

And the second (using load() and the loop above) gives

```
data: [0, 4, 1, 0, 12, 9, 0, 4, 0, 12, 0, 19, 123, 167, 149, 156, 159, 158, 170, 113 ....
```

Is it giving me the averages of the RGB components? How does it determine that if there are no RGB components and this is a grayscale image?

Besides that, is there a better way I should do this? Ideally I want something that will have the same output as getData() for a grayscale image, but can support any arbitrary number of pixel components. I know that I could simply do this by looping through each and every pixel and entering them each as individual arrays, but that will become very time and memory consuming with a large image, no?

Any advice is greatly appreciated. If anyone is wondering, the reason I need to support a high number of pixel components is because this is being written for application on data gathered from an x-ray microscope at our laboratory. While RGB has three channels, we may have over 20 channels in a single image, each one corresponding to elemental composition rather than color (Iron, Potassium, Zinc, Calcium, etc.).

Comment: If you're getting 3D images from your microscope (x-y-spectral channel), you probably need a different storage format than a (simple) RGB image.

Comment: It wont be RGB, I was just using that as an example. Each spectral channel comes as a grayscale image, they are later compiled together (I assume by color, or at least an "element" identifing value that is equivalent to separate color channel values.). Unless that is what you mean.


Either way, we are in very early stages, and getting it to first work for an RGB image is our next step. I just want to have something implemented that is open to expansion later, and won't lock us into using exactly three color channels.

Answer (score 1):

numpy (part of anaconda) can load pixel data from a PIL image using `asarray`

```
In [1]: from PIL import Image
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: x = Image.open("/tmp/kitten.jpg")
In [4]: np.asarray(x)
Out[4]:
array([[[  1,   2,  23],
    ..., dtype=uint8)
```

You'll get a 3 dimensional array, with the first two dimensions being the position of the pixel in the image, and the third dimension being the value of the pixel in the image in whatever color format the picture is in. This also has the advantage of being much faster than `getdata`.